# Writing to file with write() in Python does not work as expected

Tags: python, io

I have a very simple script to write one line to a file if the condition is true. 
the script fulfill the condition but it is not writing the line to the file. whats the problem?

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python

 import sys
 import re
 import os
 import subprocess

 curdir = os.getcwd()

 files = os.listdir(curdir)

 newpbsname = curdir.split("/")
 GROUP = []
 for i in files:
     if i.endswith(".rst"):
         rstf.append(i)
 for G in files:
     if G.startswith("ti"):
         GROUP.append(G)

 GROUPS  = sorted(GROUP)

 num = int(GROUPS[-1][-8:-6])

 OP = open(GROUPS[-1],"r")
 filn = str(GROUPS[1][0:4]) + "%d" % (num+1) + ".group"
 OT = open(filn,"w")
 if GROUPS[-1][2] == 1 :
     A = " -O -i run0_03.in -p merged_21.prmtop -c restrt0-ti_21_%d.rst   -ref merged_21.inpcrd" % (num-1)
     print A
     OT.write(A + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the file. When calling `OT.write()` the desired file is generated in your filesystem but it has not contents since it is not closed. By calling `OT.close()` the file is closed and its contents are written to the filesystem as shown by the following console output:

```
# init a file object in python
In [7]: f = open('foo.txt', 'w')

# write a sample string to the file object (IPython's output shows the bytes written)
In [8]: f.write('foo')
Out[8]: 3

# viewing foo.txt using cat does not deliver any contents
In [10]: cat foo.txt

# ll shows that foo.txt does not have any filesize
In [11]: ll
0 28 Aug 19:05 foo.txt

# close the file (file object) and see what happens
In [12]: f.close()

# after closing the file object f, cat delivers the desired output
In [13]: cat foo.txt
foo

# and ll shows that the filesize is three bytes
In [14]: ll
total 32
3 28 Aug 19:06 foo.txt
```

So the last part of your code should be something like:

```
 if GROUPS[-1][2] == 1 :
     A = " -O -i run0_03.in -p merged_21.prmtop -c restrt0-ti_21_%d.rst   -ref merged_21.inpcrd" % (num-1)
     print A
     OT.write(A + "\n")
     OT.close() # added this line
```

However, opening and closing a file to write into seems to be kind of annoying. Instead of using `.open()` and `.close()` you could use with `open(filename, mode) as f` as shown below:

```
with open(filn,"w") as OT:
    if GROUPS[-1][2] == 1 :
        A=" -O -i run0_03.in -p merged_21.prmtop -c restrt0-ti_21_%d.rst   -ref merged_21.inpcrd" % (num-1)
        print A
        OT.write(A + "\n")
```

This opens the file before doing the stuff below the `with open()` statement and closes it automatically after the stuff is done.